# Check for empty XML element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Map_Sample.Input_Schema">
<Number1>
</Number1>
<Number2>11</Number2>
<Number3>12</Number3>
</ns0:Root>
```

In this case I am getting `ENTER` or `\r\n` for `Number1`. I want to write some XSLT to check if a node contains `ENTER` or `\r\n` and then replace it `<Number1 />`.

Can anyone help me to write the XSLT for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**There are different possible definitions of what an "empty element" could mean**.

Let's define an *empty element* as one that doesn't have any element nodes children and whose string value is the empty string, or consists only of white space characters (' ', CR, NL).

**Then to check if a given element is empty, use**:

```
not(*) and not(normalize-space())
```

This assumes that the element is the context node when the XPath expression is evaluated.

> In this case I am getting "ENTER" or "\r\n" for Number1. I want to
>   write XSLT to check if node contain "ENTER" or "\r\n" then replace it
>   .

You haven't specified with what this text node should be replaced, so in this solution I am assuming the text node should be replaced with the empty string (deleted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Map_Sample.Input_Schema">
    <Number1>
    </Number1>
    <Number2>11</Number2>
    <Number3>12</Number3>
</ns0:Root>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Map_Sample.Input_Schema">
   <Number1/>
   <Number2>11</Number2>
   <Number3>12</Number3>
</ns0:Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(string(.)) = '']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explanation: skip output for elements where the (full descendants') text content is pure whitespace.